# writing the query in codeigniter giving a different result than required

Tags: codeigniter

I am working on codeigniter and I am writing the following query:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('tbl_profile');
$this->db->join('tbl_msg', 'tbl_msg.msg_sender_id = tbl_profile.profile_id');
$this->db->order_by("msg_id", "desc");
$query = $this->db->get('', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));
$data['records'] = $query->result_array();
```

Correspondingly I am getting the following result:

```
SELECT (*) FROM tbl_profile
JOIN tbl_msg ON tbl_msg.msg_sender_id = tbl_profile.profile_id
```

Which is returninng a wrong result as I want the result corresponding to the following query:

```
select * from tbl_profile as A
join (select * from tbl_msg) as B on A.profile_id = B.msg_sender_id
```

Please help

Comment: You have a possible typo (mse_sender_id/msg_sender_id). What's that <br> doing there?

Comment: I have corrected that mistake and even edited the above post.

Comment: i am getting a different result using both queries..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you missing the order by clause, but I assum, you mean other differences.

If you want that, you can use this query, what will gave you back the exact code:

```
$this->db->select('*', FALSE);
$this->db->from('tbl_profile as A');
$this->db->join('( select * from tbl_msg ) as B', 'A.msg_sender_id = B.profile_id');
$this->db->order_by("msg_id", "desc");
$query = $this->db->get('', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));
$data['records'] = $query->result_array();
```

From codeigniter user manual:

```
$this->db->select()
```

accepts an optional second parameter. If you set it to FALSE, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table names with backticks. This is useful if you need a compound select statement.

Comment: The above query is working perfectly but not with pagination . It is able to fetch only 93 records from data base.On the contrary if i am writing the result of the query(i mean as a MySql query) in MySql console then i am getting 295 records in total. Please help.

Comment: but what is the code with and without pagination? how much result do you get with them?